# How to implement a Dart priority queue (in descending order)

Tags: dart, priority-queue

In Dart, I would like to implement two priority queues, one in ascending order and one in descending order.

The SDK class `SplayTreeMap` conveniently solves the ascending order case, i.e. I can use `stm.values` to get the values in ascending order. Is there a way to get `SplayTreeMap` to return the values in descending order? (apart from the obvious solution of sorting the values afterwards on every access). For example, is there a way to override the compare function of the value types?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, just passing 'inverse' keys solved the problem (at least for my use case).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `firstKey` for finding the first element of the the acsending queue and `lastKey` for the descending queue.

Comment: Interesting to know (even though I doesn't help in my use case where actually I need the full sorted list, not just the first/last elements.) Still, thanks!